# Excel transform number into date

Tags: excel

I have dates written as numbers: `20150517`
I want to transform them into cells formated as dates: `17/05/2015`

How can I do this?

Comment: 1) read the value. 2) convert to date with `yyyyMMdd` format. 3) change format to `dd-MM-yyyy`. 4) insert in cell. 5) change cell property to date

Comment: So how do I do step 2?

Comment: Do you know how to write [VBA](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html)?

Comment: No. I'm new to Excel.

Comment: Well then step 1 changes to: Learn VBA! A tip to start: enable developer options in excel and record a macro, then analyse the VBA code (ALT + F11)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula in excel to do this:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2), RIGHT(A1,2))
```

The date formula takes three parameters: The year, The month, and The day. You can use String formulas in excel to get each part of the date from your format. `LEFT` gets the number of characters you specify from the front of the string. `MID` gets the number of characters you specify at the starting point within the string that you specify, and `RIGHT` gets the number of characters you specify from the end of the string.

Using `LEFT`, `MID`, `RIGHT` here we just pick out the Year, Month, and Date from your string (the value in `A1`) and feed them into `DATE()`.